# tween en canvas

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una animacion con la libreria de Matter.js y para poder realizar la animacion en cierto tiempo utilizo la libreria de Tween.js de la siguiente forma:

```
vaso_moleculas = Body.create({
parts: [barra_izquierda_vaso_moleculas,barra_derecha_vaso_moleculas,barra_inferior_vaso_moleculas],
restitution: 0,
friction: 0,
frictionStatic : 0,
frictionAir: 0,
inertia: Infinity,
mass: 1,
isStatic: true,
});

var cont = Matter.Body.rotate(vaso_moleculas,2);
createjs.Tween.get(vaso_moleculas).to(cont,3000);
```

cuando cargo la pagina ya aparece rotado, intente moverlo en mi codigo sigo con lo mismo.
Como podre resolverlo o no se si la libreria de tween no me permite manejar objetos de otras librerias ya que al momento de utilizarlo asi:

```
createjs.Tween.get(vaso_moleculas).to(Matter.Body.rotate(vaso_moleculas,2),3000);
```

me aparece un error de que no puedo utilizar puntos.
desafortunadamente matter.js no maneja tween fuer por eso que utilize la libreria de tween.js

Comment: Por favor, procura incluir el fragmento completo del mensaje de error.

Comment: ya no me aparece el error, como le estuve moviendo ya no me arroja error, pero cuando carga la pagina automatimante ya aparece rotado